# GN: Convert spline factor to gaussian curve function

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, splines

How would I convert spline factor into a gaussian curve using math?

I am able to do it with a float curve but would like to make it parametric.

example with float curve:

EDIT:
figured out how to implement =−^2+ as nodes to get an arc. Still not sure how to flatten out the curve at the ends.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just the slightly tedious business of converting the formula into *Math* nodes.

Here the curve is expressed in terms of **μ**, the mean, and **σ**, the standard deviation:

[image]

Here, (object-space) Y is set by the function, and the *Spline Parameter* maps X, but you could  group it up and  use it to set any other attribute..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Robin!!! You did write text in images! You must not do that. Quellenform just got a ruffle because of that (because he is "new" here). But i am sure you won't get a ruffle of that moderator because he ruffles only new guys....+1 great answer as usual ;)

Comment: @Chris :D I'm no good at mathjax, so I just grabbed the .SVG from Wikipedia and plonked it in the .blend file. It's not really part of the answer, so I just might get away with it....,

Comment: Sorry, wrote plus 1 but didn’t do it - just did it now‍♂️

Comment: Thanks Robin! this works great, I can see now that I was way off. Definitely adding the node group as a present.

Comment: @Chris https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bXvV.jpg